# Getting the rowtype of a table named after an Oracle PL/SQL keyword

Tags: plsql

I have a table named CASE.

And let's say I have the ff code:

```
declare
  a CASE%rowtype;
begin
  null;
end;
```

The above code will throw the error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CASE" when expecting one of the following: ...

Is there anyway for me to create a variable of CASE%rowtype without manually creating the datatype itself? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as `Case` is a reserved keyword,

you can escape it with double quotes

```
a "CASE"%rowtype;
```

useless to say that you should avoid reserved keywords in object naming... (or not that useless ?)